# Dan Grossman's Bootstrap Date Picker - Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using the date picker https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker to filter stats with an ajax callback.

I have extra filter options along side it on the page and I need *them* to trigger the datepicker's callback on change as well?

Any ideas how I can either trigger the callback from the other drop downs or abstract the callback function in which case i'd need to pass the start + end date's from the datepicker as parameters?

Comment: I suggest you put your code here or at least on jsfiddle...

Comment: I was going to but since it's pretty heavily tied into bootstrap it's a little difficult, I opted to post a link to the gitHub repo which has an example. All I really need to know is if I can trigger the callback externally?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not happy it's the best solution but I set 2 global vars for start and end then updated them with the callback so I can call the ajax refresh and pass the dates from anywhere.

```
var startDate = Date.today();
var endDate = Date.today();

function refresh_stats(start, end)
{
    // Do ajax refresh
}

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker(
        {
                ranges: {
                        'Today': ['today', 'today'],
                        'Yesterday': ['yesterday', 'yesterday'],
                        'Last 7 Days': [Date.today().add({ days: -6 }), 'today'],
                        'Last 30 Days': [Date.today().add({ days: -29 }), 'today'],
                        'This Month': [Date.today().moveToFirstDayOfMonth(), Date.today().moveToLastDayOfMonth()],
                        'Last Month': [Date.today().moveToFirstDayOfMonth().add({ months: -1 }), Date.today().moveToFirstDayOfMonth().add({ days: -1 })]
                }
        }, 
        function(start, end)
        {
                startDate = start;
                endDate = end;
                refresh_stats(start, end);
        }
);

// Then can call this whenever
refresh_stats(startDate, endDate);
```